# How do I programmatically add a keybinding in a VS Code Extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

On Gboard, pressing that caps button changes the casing of the texting to lower/title/uppercase. [Gboard change case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCyos.gif)

I'm trying to create a VS Code extension that does the same when I press Caps Lock.

I've added a command Change Case that can be executed from the command pallette. [Change Case extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8QmA.gif)

I know I can manually bind a Caps Lock to my command but I was wondering if there's a way to do this programmatically so that anyone who installs this extension doesn't have to manually bind the key.

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.keybindings

Comment: Thanks, [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836330/mark) for your comment. I don't know how I missed that. I checked the contribution points documentation before but missed it. I feel silly but I won't delete this question in case other beginners like myself need it in the future.